# What is window.route in javascript. what does it do?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, browser

I have been studying about Single Page Application and where I ran into window.route = route() function. I can't understand this line properly. See the last line of the code.

```
const route = (event)=>{
    event = event || window.event;
    event.preventDefault();
    window.history.pushState({},"",event.target.href);
    handlerLocation();
}

const routes={
    "404":"404.html",
    "/": "/SPA/index.html",
    "/contact":"/SPA/contact.html",
    "/about":"/SPA/about.html"
}

async function handlerLocation(){
    const path = window.location.pathname;
    const route = routes[path]||routes["404"]
    const html = await fetch(route).then(data=> data.text());
    document.getElementById("main-div").innerHTML = html;
}

window.onpopstate=handlerLocation;
handlerLocation();



//this is the line
window.route=route;
```

Comment: There is no built-in called `route` on window, it is just something that the author of the above script thought up and used.

Comment: It's the same as `window.whateveryoulike`,  your basically assigning a function called route, to a property called route on the window global.  Not sure were your studying this code from, but there a couple of things I'd say is not good coding standards.

Answer (score 0):

This line creates new property for the window object.
Window instance don't have a property called route, ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

As the look of it, it is a custom application modification to the object.